# PHP - Trim Function Only Taking Effect On First Character?

Tags: php, trim

I'm trying to trim the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get rid of the .php file trailing it. But after investigating because it wasn't trimming, I trimmed /, I then found that it is only trimming the first character in the REQUEST_URI.

```
<? var_dump (trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')); ?>
```

This returns string(37) "ncms/admin/login.php?p=login&failed=1"

You can see it only is trimming the first / before ncms.

Here is the untouched string,

```
string(37) "/ncms/admin/login.php?p=login&failed=1"
```

Why is it only effecting the first character?

Comment: "Why is it only effecting the first character?" -- it's by definition: "trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string" http://php.net/trim

Comment: [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) has a man page. It affects the characters on either end.

Comment: How do I trim all the /'s out of the string?

Comment: With [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace). But that's not what you actually want either.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `trim()`, but you need [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
str_replace('/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace will affect whole variable

```
str_replace('/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```